# Kotlin chaining collection functions performance

Tags: intellij-idea, kotlin

I am new to Kotlin and I am learning the language by solving simple puzzles in IntelliJ, using the tips presented by the IDE. I wrote this piece of code (Finding the most repeated number):

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val tracer = mutableMapOf<Int,Int>()
    var currentMaxCount = 0

    val numbers = readLine()!!.split(' ').map(String :: toInt)

    for(number in numbers) {
        val currentCountOfNum = incrementAndGetCurrentCountOf(number, tracer)
        currentMaxCount = if(currentCountOfNum > currentMaxCount) currentCountOfNum else currentMaxCount
    }

    println(currentMaxCount)
}

fun incrementAndGetCurrentCountOf(num : Int, tracer: MutableMap<Int,Int>) =
        if(tracer[num] == null) {
            tracer.put(num, 1)
            1
        } else {
            val newCount = tracer[num]!! + 1
            tracer.put(num, newCount)
            newCount
        }
```

And the IDE suggested that the following code:

```
    var currentMaxCount = 0
    for(number in numbers) {
            val currentCountOfNum = incrementAndGetCurrentCountOf(number, tracer)
            currentMaxCount = if(currentCountOfNum > currentMaxCount) currentCountOfNum else currentMaxCount
        }
```

be changed to this:

```
val currentMaxCount = numbers
            .map { incrementAndGetCurrentCountOf(it, tracer) }
            .max()
            ?: 0
```

I understand what is happening. But I was wondering if the performance would become O(2n) if I use the IDE's suggestion. It's O(n) in what I came up with. I know it theoretically doesn't make a difference, but I would like know if Kotlin uses any magic to keep the running time at O(n). (Any additional suggestions to further shrink the code are welcome)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**TL;DR**

Yes, there is a performance impact because those are actually two separate iterations.

In this particular context, you can avoid doing the additional iteration by leveraging a dedicated `maxBy` method:

```
numbers.maxBy { incrementAndGetCurrentCountOf(it, tracer) } ?: 0
```

---

It's important to remember that Kotlin Collections, unlike Java Streams, are not lazy and all those fancy methods encapsulate simple imperative implementations.

So `M` chained `map` calls result in O(M*N) in the optimistic case even if the whole processing could be short-circuited because visiting all elements is not necessary:

```
listOf(1, 2, 3)
      .map {
          println(it)
      }.first()
```

this prints:

```
1
2
3
```

In such situations, it's important to remember about the existence of `asSequence` method which creates a lazily evaluated sequence backed by a given collection:

```
listOf(1, 2, 3).asSequence()
      .map {
          println(it)
      }.first()
```

which prints:

```
1
```

Comment: Thank you! I saw the code for maxBy, and it is doing exactly what I am doing (transforming and keeping track of the maximum in the same loop). But I don't get how mapTo function is doing exactly what I am doing. mapTo is just transforming, but I am both transforming and keeping track of max element in the same loop. This seemed to take two loops in the IDE suggested code.

Comment: @AndrewNessin yeah, I answered slightly different version of your question :) let me rephrase that

Comment: @AndrewNessin actually, thanks for the question. I will dedicate the whole article to this topic and cover it broader :) check 4comprehension.com